# How could I use both Rendered Entity and Fields in a view?

Tags: views

I like my *Rendered entity* style, but I want to add in just a couple of extra fields.

Under "Fields", it says

> The selected style or row format does not utilize fields.

Is this possible in any way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured out this IS possible, just have to switch things around.

Format to show *Fields* rather than *Rendered entity*. Then you have the option to use the rendered entity as a field. Something like this:

[image]

shows up in the Add fields list.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to add the Field you want to add in the display of your entity itself, not in the view. If your rendered entity is one of the base entities of drupal (node/taxonomy term/...) you can use the UI to add or remove fields from their display.

To edit the display of a node for example go:

Structure > Content types > YOUR CONTENTTYPE > edit display

You can not add fields to a rendered entity using views I am afraid.